# c# implicit casts of generic types

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to understand implicit casts on generic types.
The following lines of codes won't compile:

```
class Dataset : Dictionary<string, string>
{
}

class Section : List<Dataset>
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ToBase()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

However, if I add the following implicit operator to the Section class they compile.

```
public static implicit operator List<Dictionary<string, string>>(Section section)
{
    return section;
}
```

What do these lines really change? (By the way: ReSharper now shows an "Conversion to base class" error, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Could anyone please explain to me what's going on here??
Thanks!!

Comment: _"won't compile"_ - why not? Share the compiler errors and show your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `List<Dataset>` to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, because `List<T>` isn't covariant (and only interfaces in C# can be covariant, so you would need a `IList<T>`, but `IList<T>` isn't covariant)

Note that this:

```
public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> ToBase()
{
    return this;
}
```

is legal, because `IEnumerable<>` is covariant, so you can cast a `IEnumerable<subclass>` to a `IEnumerable<baseclass>`

To give some examples:

```
Section section = new Section();

List<Dataset> sectionAsList = section; // Legal

List<Dictionary<string, string>> sectionAsListDictionary = section; // Illegal
IList<Dictionary<string, string>> sectionAsIListDictionary = section; // Illegal

IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> sectionAsIEnumerableDictionary = section; // Legal
```